# What's the onomatopoeia of a champagne bottle being popped out?

Tags: word-request

Just a reminder that an onomatopoeia is basically a word which imitates the natural sounds of a thing. I am not sure what are the possible onomatopoeia associated with the popping out of a champagne bottle. I imagine there are a dozen, but I want the ones that are the most widely used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already said it - the best word is *pop!*

EDIT: J.R. points out that *pop the cork* is a very common idiomatic expression that describes the opening of a champagne bottle.

Comment: Worth noting (and feel free to add this to your answer if you want): the expression *pop the cork* is so idiomatic that it [even appears in some dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pop%20the%20cork).

Comment: Shirley Bassey, a famous Welsh singer, wisely didn't pop her cork for every guy she saw.